# Rewrite URL to point to another site in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

I have two sites set up in IIS 8.5, which for the sake of simplicity let's call **Test 1** and **Test 2**.

**Test 1** can be accessed at `test1.mydomain.com`, and **Test 2** can be accessed at `test2.mydomain.com`, but I want it to also be available at `test1.mydomain.com/app`.

This shouldn't be a redirect, but a rewrite - when the user is viewing the **Test 2** site, they should see the URL `test1.mydomain.com/app` in their browser address bar, and all paths should use this as the base url, e.g. `test1.mydomain.com/app/page1`

I was hoping that this would be simple with the URL rewrite module, but it doesn't appear to be possible to rewrite the domain, only the path:

```
    <rule name="test2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^app(/.*)?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="test2.mydomain.com{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

Adding this to the web.config of **Test 1** results in a 404 error, I assume because it rewrites the URL as `test1.mydomain.com/test2.mydomain.com`

**How can I rewrite the URL to point at the Test 2 site?**

Comment: Mistake 3, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The domain name cannot be rewritten using URL Rewrite, and URL Rewrite can only rewrite the content behind the domain name.**

You can use the reverse proxy in ARR to achieve this function:

[image]

Here are the steps to configure reverse proxy:

1. If you have not installed [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing), you need to install it first.
2. Double-click ARR after successful installation:

[image]

3. Set up reverse proxy:

[image]

4. Enable reverse proxy:

[image]

5. Finally, configure a URL Rewrite in your site:

[image]

For more information about "Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

**UPDATE:**

You can enable FRT to see what the rewritten URL is.

Here is a demo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can try to use this rule:

```
<rule name="test2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^app(/.*)?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test2.mydomain.com{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

**Use this action:**

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://test2.mydomain.com{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

**Don't forget to add http://.**

Comment: I've enabled proxy in ARR, but this rewrite still redirects me to a 404 page, so I assume there must be a problem with my rewrite rule. Is there an easy way to find the full URL which is being produced by the rewrite?

Comment: Ah, I'm using IIS6 so unfortunately I don't have this feature. I'll update my original question to inlcude this info.

Comment: I was confused. I'm actually on IIS 8.5 running on Windows Server 6.2, only Failed Request Tracing was not installed. I've installed it and updated my question.

Unfortunately, the failed request logs don't contain the rewritten URLs, and a search for "REWRITE_ACTION" gets no results.

Comment: Add http:// to the ULR of action. Remember to clear the browser cache and restart IIS.

Comment: In addition, for your initial question, I think I have answered you, we can use ARR to complete this requirement. In order for other people in the community to find this post when this problem exists, if you have other questions, you can reopen a new post and I will reply to you.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this working, but thankyou for all your help.

Comment: Adding test2.mydomain.com to the hosts file fixed the issue I was having - marking this as the accepted answer, because as you said it fully addresses my original question. Thanks again.